# How to remove un used protobuf methods when compilation

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

We have a huge mesh of protobufs which are pointing to a one single protobuf message. So now the problem is when we try to use this with Android, android compiler runs out of maximum number of methods a singe project can have. But again this specific android part of the project really need 5% of the original protobuf file. Is there any solution of a special compiler which finds out which methods are used and not used and omit them from compiled code. Or is there any other wasy to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there any other wasy to work around this?

Use the "nano version" of protobuf, [as outlined in the README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+/master/java/README.txt). Or, use [Square's wire](https://github.com/square/wire). There may be other reduced-method version of the protobuf client library/generator floating around as well.